# Solving a logarithmic equation containing an exponent

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

[image]

I'm having trouble finding the solution to this problem. I'm unsure how to go about solving the equation in regards to the exponent. Moving the 2 in front of the (ln x) would make the equation equate to 0=0 which is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x)=0$ then
\begin{align}
0 &= (\ln x )^2 - 2 \ln x \\
\iff 0 &= u^2-2u\, \qquad (u=\ln x) \\
\iff 0 &= u(u-2) \\
\iff &u=0\,  \text{or}\,  u = 2
\end{align}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah, that makes it much clearer thanks!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}f(x)=0&\iff\ln(x)^2=2\ln(x)\\&\iff\ln(x)=0\vee\ln(x)=2\\&\iff x=1\vee x=e^2.\end{align*}

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Yes, I know that. And... ?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Because $f(x)=\ln(x)^2-2\ln(x)$ and therefore $f(x)=0\iff\ln(x)^2=2\ln(x)$. What's the problem?

Comment: @MatthewBolster See my solution below for a further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(\ln x)^2 \ne \ln (x^2)$$

solve the equation 
$$
(\ln x)^2-2 \ln x=0
$$
with the substitution $\ln x=t$

Comment: @Kevin: Thank you. I edit the typo ..